# Customize Certain cmsComponents that seem NOT to be overridable

Tags: spartacus-storefront

There seem to be certain Components in spartacus that are not meant to be overridden.
For Example every Component used INSIDE "CartDetailsComponent".

For example I need to do a couple of html tweaks on the "cx-cart-item" Component, but unfortunately this component is not served as overridable.

Trying to Reference it in my module with

```
B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig({
cmsComponents: {
        CartItemComponent: {
          component: CUSTOMComponent
        }
```

does not have an effect since this component is not referenced in a provider like this

```
  providers: [
    provideDefaultConfig(<CmsConfig>{
      cmsComponents: {
        CartComponent: {
          component: CartDetailsComponent,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
```

So the closest Component would be CartDetails (respectively CartComponent).
But this means, that in order to achieve a slightly altered html inside CartItem, I need to override CartComponent, and then copy & paste the entire logic (ts and html) for not only this component, but also CartItemList and finally CartItem itself.

This looks some ridiculously insane amount of effort for a simple html tweak.
Is this really a shortcoming that we just have to deal with right now, or is there another to master such requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize such components via remapping it like a CMS Component, you should customize it over higher lever CMS Component.

And here you can find GitHub issue https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/4441, which relates to above problem and similar Stack Overflow question - [How to customize lower level components in Spartacus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62157099/how-to-customize-lower-level-components-in-spartacus/).