# How to customize lower level components in Spartacus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to customize the `ProductListItemComponent` and the `ProductGridItemComponent` in order to add some more functionality like a *Stock counter*.

After some quick research I came to the conclusion that they can't be remapped using the `cmsComponents` object, only the actual CMS Component, the `CMSProductListComponent`, can be remapped.

If my assumption is correct, what would be the best approach on customizing these components?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup!

You are right! You can't customize `ProductListItemComponent` or `ProductGridItemComponent` via remapping it like a CMS Component, you should customize it over higher lever CMS Component - `ProductListComponent`.

And here you can find GitHub issues: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/4231 and https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/4441, which relates to above problem.