# How to override/extend ProductGridItemComponent using an outlet in Spartacus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I got a case where I should override/extend that `ProductGridItemComponent`, in the electronics-spa base-site.
Normally when overriding components in Spartacus one could add an outlet template like this:

```
<ng-template cxOutletRef="ProductGridItemComponent">
  My custom code here
</ng-template>
```

But this doesn't seem to have any effect. If I try to override the `ProductListComponent` is works but then I would have to copy a lot of code from the source code to make it behave and look as the provided code from Spartacus.
Is it possible to override only the `ProductGridItemComponent` or do I have to do override the `ProductListComponent` and build it up from scratch?

-- EDIT --

I found the answer on another thread.
[How to customize lower level components in Spartacus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62157099/how-to-customize-lower-level-components-in-spartacus/)

The `ProductGridItemComponent` is not customizable. It has to be done on a higher level, `ProductListComponent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like `ProductGridItemComponent` has available outlets for customization.  The alternative is to extend and override the component to customize its behaviour.

Comment: Do you mean that I should extend and override ```ProductGridItemComponent``` or ```ProductListComponent```?
Can you show me an example on how to do that?

Comment: I don't know exactly which you should override for your need, but you can override and extend the components you need to customizes if the don't offer outlets.  You can take a look at this doc for info on how to do that https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/